# Conjunction of concepts before auto?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm learning C++20 concepts. Is there a way to do a conjunction of concepts in-place before an `auto`? For example, If I have a `MutableGraph<G>` concept and a `VertexListGraph<G>` concept, I could define

```
template <typename G>
concept MutableVertexListGraph = MutableGraph<G> && VertexListGraph<G>;
```

and do

```
MutableVertexListGraph auto g = ...;
```

but it's annoying to name the concept when it's just that I want it to model both concepts. It would be nice if I could do

```
MutableGraph && VertexListGraph auto g = ...; // && not allowed here.
```

or even something like

```
template <typename T, concept... Concepts> // <- "concept" not allowed here.
concept ModelsAll = (Concepts<T> && ...);
...
ModelsAll<MutableGraph, VertexListGraph> auto g = ...;
```

I can of course do

```
MutableGraph auto g = ...;
requires { MutableGraph<decltype(g)>; };
```

which lacks symmetry, or

```
auto g = ...;
requires { MutableGraph<decltype(g)>; MutableGraph<decltype(g)>; };
```

which lacks the concept on the declaration line.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if you can do this (which I'm pretty sure you know you can't), or why can't you do it?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to do something like this since the things I guessed at didn't seem to work. I suspect the answer is "no" but being new to the various things you can and can't do with concepts, I wasn't sure. (Or alternately, I'm wondering if this is the sort of thing that might be desirable in future standards, like `MutableGraph && VertexListGraph auto g = ...;` or `(MutableGraph && VertexListGraph) auto g = ...;`.)

Comment: You didn't mention `template< class G > requires (MutableGraph<G> and VertexListGraph<G>) T g = ...`. Is it too much typing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to combine concepts when applying constraints to a deduced variable definition's type.

`ConceptName auto variable = ...;` is fairly readable. The `ConceptName` is probably pretty self-explanatory, and it leaves plenty of room for the variable definition.

`Concept1 && Concept2 && Concept3 auto variable = ...;` is a lot less readable. At that point, the sequence of concepts crowds out the actually important parts of the statement: the variable declaration. As such, splitting it into multiple statements makes a lot more sense:

```
auto variable = ...;
static_assert(Concept1<decltype(variable)> && Concept2<decltype(variable)> && Concept3<decltype(variable)>);
```

This involves a very unfortunate amount of `decltype` usage (which an additional `using` statement could avoid), but it does separate the concerns, making the `variable` declaration itself more readable.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. I gather writing `requires requires` is an anti-pattern indicating there's a concept that should be named. This is arguably related. For my particular example, `VertexListGraph` is "more fundamental" so I could see `VertexListGraph auto g = ...; requires { MutableGraph<decltype(g)>; }; // It needs to be mutable too.`

Comment: @Ben: You can't put a `requires` constraint on a variable declaration. That `requires` expression will do nothing, regardless of how `MutableGraph<decltype(g)>` works out. It will evaluate to `true` or `false`, and you never use the result, so it gets dropped. That's why I used a `static_assert`.

Comment: Good catch. I noticed it compiled but didn't check that it worked.